# SelectFrame - switchTo().frame WEBDRIVER

Tags: c#, webdriver

Using webdriver (in C# not java) I want to selectframe, but this line is not working to me:

```
            driver.switchTo().frame("ifr");
```

which Hierarchy I must write about selectframe? I never use selectFrame in a proyect

I have this only:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
```

Comment: What is selectFrame? Do you want to switch to `iframe` or something else?

Comment: Really I want only to click in a button recorded which command is selectFrame (I don't know what it's) and which target is ifr. I suppose that "switch" in english in like "select/click", no? how can i do iframe?

Comment: @Lion6 - please post an example of URL page and scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform some action (click a button) which is inside an iFrame, you need to switch to it (move focus / "zoom-in") because by default you are on the top parent.

Example: In order to get the text from the colored iFrame from here http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_height_width first you need to do

```
 <'WebDriver'>.switchTo().frame(<'frameId'>)
```

and after that you will be able to get the text.

[image: iFrame name to be used]